# my ajax comment doesn't let it run but it works fine

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

why is my ajax even though i have commented it doesn't run but it works fine and when i add a click event it doesn't run even though my path is correct:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#check-login").click(function(){
        email = $("#email").val();
        password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/PhoneAccessories/api/checklogin",
            type:"GET",
            data:{
                employee_email:email,
                employee_password:password,
                
            },
            success: function(value){
                alert(value);
                
                if(value == "true"){
                    path = window.location.href
                    newPath = path.replace("login/","")
                    window.location = newPath;
                }else{
                    
                    $(".login-failed").text("login failed")
                }
                
                
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Add failure and error handlers. BTW: this Ajax is very old and deprecated.

Comment: This is jQuery Javascript? Please add names and tags. Will help you get attention of right developers. Java is different